# File too large to upload to server even when php.ini file altered

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, file-upload

I have been unable to upload a ([.OBJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)) file to the server and get an 'Error 1' meaning that

> The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini

I got this information from this page - http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

I then went to the php.ini file and changed both the `upload_max_filesize` and the `post_max_size` to **10000M**.

I still get an 'Error 1' when I try to upload the file even though it is only 3MB. I have also restarted the server so that changes I have made to the php.ini file can come into effect. I know that my code works for smaller files as I have been able to send a small TXT file that contains the word "Test".

Here is the form.php file that contains the PHP code for handling the sent file on the server side and HTML code to create the file selection and upload functionality.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000000);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    var_dump($_FILES);
    echo "<br/><b>File Name:</b> " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "<b>Type:</b> " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "<b>Size:</b> " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "<b>Temp File Name:</b> " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    echo "<b>Error:</b> " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";

    $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];            // Storing source path of the file in a variable
    $targetPath = "upload/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];    // Target path where file is to be stored

    move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath);

    exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>File</label>
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"> 
    </form>
    <div></div>
</body>
<script>

$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (res) {
                $('div').html(res);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
</html>
```

To sum up my question is, why can I not upload the desired file even though I have changed the appropriate variables of the php.ini file?

Comment: Print the phpinfo page and check the values there: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: @vsakos I have checked the values with phpinfo() and it says that the `upload_max_filesize` is set to 2M. So it hasn't been updated. I'm still having difficulties updating this value as I've now tried restarting the Apache Webserver which hasn't changed anything unfortunately.

Comment: @vsakos I must have been updating a different php.ini file. I went to the php.ini file directory stated on the phpinfo() page and updated the `upload_max_filesize` and it worked! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to restart you Webserver:

```
service apache restart #If you have Apache
service nginx restart #If you have NGINX
```

If your running php-fpm:

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Do you have multiple php.ini's?
Look out for:

```
/etc/php/php-fpm
/etc/php/php-cli
/etc/php/php-cgi
```

Under some circumstances you also have to allow bigger file uploads on your Webserver.

NGINX:

```
client_max_body_size 10000M;
```

Comment: I restarted the Apache Webserver but still get an 'Error 1'. I don't seem to have multiple php.ini's.

Comment: I was altering the wrong php.ini file. Restarting the Webserver must have also been a key step. Thanks!

Comment: Yup. When you use "normal" php and not php-fpm, you have to restart your apache so the new settings in php.ini get loaded. Have a good one

Answer (score 0):

Jquery ajax transfer from client to sever just only data, not file. If you want to transfer file using jquery ajax, then try this [jquery extended library](https://github.com/xiidea/jquery-form-transport). I have used it before and it worked fine.